# How to Evaluate an Attribute Inside a Nested Python Dict Comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary-comprehension

When running the following code, Python2.7 throws a NameError. This happens when the second dict, `paychecks`, is evaluated. The first dict, `employees`, is fine.

```
employees = { employee.ID:employee for employee in company.employees }

paychecks = {
    paycheck.ID:paycheck for paycheck in employee.paychecks
    for key, employee in employees
    }

!!! NameError: global name 'employee' is not defined
```

Is this invalid Python or a bug in my code? And what's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to list your loops in the same order you'd nest them; you have the order backwards. You also need to use the `dict.items()` method to yield both keys *and* values. This works:

```
paychecks = {paycheck.ID: paycheck
    for key, employee in employees.items()
    for paycheck in employee.paychecks}
```

as you need to first loop over `employees` before `employee` is set.

For list, dict and set comprehensions, picture the loops as nested `for` statements:

```
for key, employee in employees.items():
    for paycheck in employee.paychecks:
        paychecks[paycheck.ID] = paycheck
```

If you were to nest the loops in the order you specified them, it should immediately be clear why you get a `NameError` on `employee`:

```
for paycheck in employee.paychecks:
    for key, employee in employees.items():
        paychecks[paycheck.ID] = paycheck
```

Here the outer loop tries to access a non-existing `employee` object.